# What does OFFLINE rpc command in multichain does?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info-api

What does OFFLINE rpc command in multichain does ? where to use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start MultiChain in **offline** mode, so that it does not accept incoming (or create outgoing) peer-to-peer connections. For stronger security, use **multichaind-cold**, whose peer-to-peer networking code is disabled at compile time – see cold nodes and wallets for more information.